# dynamic search for a list of values using Pipes in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2,
Could someone let me know how to implement a dynamic search option for a list of values in Angular2. As when I type the word, the list has to populate only with the searched values. I've tried using ng2-pipes, ngx-pipes, angular pipes, Ng2FilterPipeModule. But it seems not working. 
This is the HTML section

```
   <input type="text" #mySearch placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="queryString">

  <div> Part ID </div>
  <div >Part Description</div>
  <div >Quantity </div>

 <div *ngFor="let vanInventory of showPartsOnVan | FilterPipe: queryString">
   <div class="col-4 align-left">{{vanInventory.partID}} </div>
   <div class="col-5 align-left">{{vanInventory.partDesc}}</div>
   <div class="col-3 align-left">{{vanInventory.quantity}}</div>
</div>
```

And this is my Pipe.ts file

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class Ng2FilterPipeModule implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug your pipe you see the desired array in the return statement ?

Comment: Nope, Infact the code does not even compile properly using these pipes. I've even imported the Pipe and Pipe Transform in my App Modules.

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: Compile error would be useful. I've also heard it mentioned that you shouldn't really perform filtering and ordering in pipes, as they're done every time the component is rendered which may be more times than needed. So performance wise it's a bad idea. I'd have a `showPartsOnVanFiltered` in the component to bind to, updating on `OnChanges` hook.

Comment: related, suggested reading :) https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @Gili, I'm getting the error like this "The pipe 'FilterPipe' could not be found (""

Comment: Did you declare it in your module?

Comment: yes I did, In fact, previously the component I'm using was referring to a parent module, but since I've got this `pipe could not be found ` error, I've created a module within the component and declared it like `@NgModule({
    declarations: [TechnicianPipe],
    exports: [TechnicianPipe]
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer https://plnkr.co/edit/I7ljThUro6lBEk2v7nEj?p=preview .This uses a pipe for filtering the results based on the value typed in.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], criteria: any): any {

        return items.filter(item =>{
           for (let key in item ) {
             if((""+item[key]).includes(criteria)){
                return true;
             }
           }
           return false;
        });
    }
}
```

In app module

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ App,SearchFilter ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
```

Comment: I've tried as per your code, but Im getting an compiler error like,
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'searchFilter' could not be found ("**